# Многопоточность в javafx

Tags: многопоточность, javafx

Сначала отрабатывает задержка в 1 с, а затем только меняется цвет кнопки.
В чём ошибка?

```
public void btnClick(ActionEvent actionEvent)  {
        btn.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('img/Yellow.png');");
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            //Действия
            //Если выполняете действия в JavaFX
            //Пример: Platform.runLater(() -> {
            //    vBox.getChildren().add(finalPane);
            //})
            return null;
        }
    };


    Thread thread = new Thread(task); //передаём в поток
    thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Platform.runLater` выполняет код в UI потоке, следовательно у вас возможно происходит ситуация когда картинка загрузилась, но UI поток уже уснул и стиль не успел обновиться.